In WPF, why is the tooltip not displaying the error?
Here is a default style for my TextBox, when error occurs, I would like to present the same tooltip style whether the user is hovering on the field or when the user is hovering on the error icon.
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 3"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Image 
                        DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                        Width="15" Height="15"
                        Margin="-25,0,0,0"
                        Source="/Resources/error.png">
                        <Image.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"
                                Foreground="White"
                                Background="Red">
                            </ToolTip>
                        </Image.ToolTip>
                    </Image>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="myControl"/>
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget}"
                             Foreground="White"
                             Background="Red">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}" DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent" />
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


This displays OK when the end user is hovering on the field, however when the end user is hovering on the Error icon, the tooltip displays without any text in it.  What's wrong?


If the tooltip is set this way I get a similar outcome as above.
 <Image 
     DockPanel.Dock="Right"
     Width="15" Height="15"
     Margin="-25,0,0,0"
     Source="/Resources/error.png">
     <Image.ToolTip>
         <ToolTip
             Foreground="White"
             Background="Red">
             <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)}" DisplayMemberPath="ErrorContent" />
         </ToolTip>
     </Image.ToolTip>
 </Image>

If the tooltip is set against the Image this way, then it works but the tooltip is rendered in the default style which is undesirable when the end user hovers a pixel to the left or right the tooltip displayed there would be of a different style.
<Image 
    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
    ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"
    Width="15" Height="15"
    Margin="-25,0,0,0"
    Source="/Resources/error.png">
</Image>

Edit: remove a rogue Tooltip node in the last code snippet.  The question remains the same. Also added screenshot to illustrate the issue.

Hello! Could you provide the ViewModel or at least the part that has your property you have binded?

Re ViewModel, it is any that implements INotifyDataErrorInfo. When validation occurs, viewModel returns a string collection of errors for any given property name.

The only thing I see is that the Binding Path is not pointing to correct value or the value isn't updating. Instead of the ItemsControl can you use a label? Just to troubleshoot.
Something isn't right with this binding here: 

The key difference above are that, one use
   ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}"

``` and the other has  

<Image.ToolTip>



</Image.ToolTip>
it is the same when I change ItemsSource binding to have ElementName=myControl and prefix Validation.Errors with "AdornedElement".
